# Qt QTabWidget in QScroll area : concurrent scrolling

Tags: qt, scroll, focus

I have a QTabWidget some levels deeper in a QScrollArea. In Qt, there is the built-in possibility to use the mouse scroll wheel to cycle through tabs.

However, in my situation, this will also cause the QScrollArea to scroll up or down - which is super annoying.

This is undesired. I would like the tab bar to completely consume the scroll event and hide it entirely from the scroll area, to allow smooth, continuous scrolling through my tabs. Is that possible ?

Of note that I have other spin boxes and combo boxes that do show this behavior natively. I saw that they have the focus policy set to `WheelFocus`, which I now have set for my QTabWidget as well - to no avail.

I have also set the focus policy of the *tab bar* of the QTabWidget (`myTabWidget->tabBar()`) to `WheelFocus` via a line of code, also to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found that an answer could be that `QTabBar` does have the right kind of focus to be passed wheel events, but it overrides & reimplements `QWidget::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event)` in a way that does switch tabs as expected, but that doesn't `QEvent::accept` the event, i.e. consume it. Rather, on top of the tab-switching code, it simply calls the parent implementation in `QWidget`, which actually `QEvent::ignore`s the `QWheelEvent`. Thus the `QWheelEvent` gets passed up in the parent hierarchy all the way up to my `QScrollArea` which also decides to scroll.

(In comparison, things like `QComboBox`es do override `QWidget::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event)` with a call to `QEvent::accept` at the end of their reimplementation. So this really seems to be the deciding factor.)

One way to fix this would be to subclass `QTabBar` and override and reimplement `QWidget::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event)` with a call to `QEvent::accept`.

But since I use the designer, I do not have access to the `QTabBar` itself, rather only to the `QTabWidget`, which internally creates and sets its `QTabBar`.

I am however able to subclass `QTabWidget` and `QEvent::accept` the `QWheelEvent` there (and ask the designer to treat my `QTabWidget` as this new derived subclass), but it means that if I scroll *anywhere* on the `QTabWidget` then the event is consumed, whereas I only want this behavior *on the `QTabBar`* - else `QEvent::ignore`.

So I added a small piece of code to find out if the event originated from a location that is within the tab bar.

```
class ScrollableTabWidget : public QTabWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    explicit ScrollableTabWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr)
        : QTabWidget(parent) {}

    virtual ~ScrollableTabWidget() {}

    void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent * event) override
    {
        QWidget::wheelEvent(event);
        if(this->tabBar()->rect().contains(this->tabBar()->mapFromGlobal(event->globalPos())))
        {
            event->accept();
        }
    };
};
```

And then go to designer, right-click on the `QTabWidget` and ask "Use a placeholder for custom class" or something. It will ask for the class name and header file where the declarations are located, and then that's it ! This does the job.

To be fair the event should be accepted natively in Qt ... I am using Qt 5.12.11 but even in Qt 6+ the problem is still there (see code, a call to `QEvent::accept` was inserted as part of a larger commit with more changes, but the method still finishes with `QWidget::wheelEvent` which means a call to `QEvent::ignore` ... I think, anyways).